# Make CAPSLOCK work properly when single-, double-, and combo-pressed

Tags: autohotkey

I want to write an `AutoHotKey` script on Windows 10 that gives `CAPSLOCK` more functionality. My goals with `CAPSLOCK` are three-fold:

1. When single-pressed, `CAPSLOCK` works as usual.
2. When double-pressed (pressed twice in a short time), `CAPSLOCK` fires an `ESC` key. The status/light of `CAPSLOCK` should remain the same as before, but I am okay if the light went on and off, or off and on.
3. When `CAPSLOCK` are held down, in combination with `JKLI`, `CAPSLOCK + JKLI` will function as arrow keys (`left`, `down`, `right`, `up`). **Like in goal 2, the status/light of `CAPSLOCK` should remain the same as before.** (*I am okay if the light went on and off in the process, so long the terminal status is correct*).

If I only needed goal #1 and goal #3, the following script would work just fine.

```
CapsLock & J::Send {Left}
CapsLock & K::Send {Down}
CapsLock & L::Send {Right}
CapsLock & I::Send {Up}
```

However, now I want to achieve goal #2 as well, and added some more lines before it, as follows

```
~CapsLock::
    KeyWait, CapsLock
    KeyWait, CapsLock, D T0.2
    if not ErrorLevel
        Send {Escape}
Return

CapsLock & J::Send {Left}
CapsLock & K::Send {Down}
CapsLock & L::Send {Right}
CapsLock & I::Send {Up}
```

Now I am having the problem: goal #1 and goal #2 are achieved, but goal #3 is not. The status/light of `CAPSLOCK` would change after say I pressed `CAPSLOCK + L`. This is not what I want -- I want holding down `CAPSLOCK` and pressing `L` to move cursor to the right, and I want this behavior to have ***no*** effect on the status of `CAPSLOCK`.

Please let me know how to achieve my three goals with `CAPSLOCK` using `AutoHotKey`. Any help is much appreciated!

*By the way, I am working on a Lenovo Thinkpad T* model produced in 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a timer to restore the CapsLock state after it has been changed in a combination:

```
Capslock::
    If (A_PriorHotKey = "~Capslock Up" AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400 AND A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 50) ; double-press
        Send, {Esc} 
    SetTimer, RestoreCapslockState, 50
return

~Capslock Up:: return ; The tilde prefix (~) prevents AHK from blocking the key-down/up events

CapsLock & J::Send {Left}
CapsLock & K::Send {Down}
CapsLock & L::Send {Right}
CapsLock & I::Send {Up}

RestoreCapslockState:   
    KeyWait, Capslock ; wait for Capslock to be released
    SetTimer, RestoreCapslockState, OFF
    If (A_PriorKey != "Capslock") 
        SetCapsLockState % !GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") ; Toggles CapsLock to its opposite state, requires [v1.1.30+]
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetNumScrollCapsLockState.htm#ex2

Comment: Thanks for the script and explanation ! Quite unexpected as adding one functionality will need so much more code. I will be away from my Windows laptop during the weekend. Will definitely try it after I come back.

Comment: Hi, it seems to be working after I tried for first 10 minutes! Please allow me another 1-2 days to test it in daily use (I am on Windows only in my leisure time). If it is okay, I will definitely tick this answer. Otherwise, I will let you know my follow-up feedback and questions. Thanks!

Comment: A follow-up comment here: If I want to block the normal function of caps lock, but maintain all the other functions above (i.e. double pressing caps lock triggers `Esc`, and holding down caps lock + letters triggers arrow keys), all I need to modify is to change the two occurences of `~Capslock` into `Capslock`. I have tried on my PC and it seems to work. @user3419297 Could you please confirm this, please? Thanks!

Comment: In that case you can add **`SetCapslockState AlwaysOFF`** to the autoexecute-section (top of the script) and remove the timer.